# Install extensions on Visual Studio 2017 Mac

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I'm running the 2017 version of Visual Studio on my mac and I can't find any of the extensions that I need (that are available on windows). To get to the extensions I've done this: visual studio community -> extensions -> search the extensions I need.

The extensions I'm looking for are the following:

- ASP.NET and web development
- Azure development
- .NET desktop development
- Universal windows platform development
- Linux development with C++

Does anyone know where I can find them and download them for mac?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac is, in reality, a completely unrelated product. You cannot expect extensions for one to work in the other.

Comment: The [installation instructions for VS2017 for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2017) show a step where you select what workloads you want to install (and what you are describing are workloads, not extensions). With VS2017, you can only install .NET Core applications, so no .NET desktop development, no UWP. You might have better luck with VS2019 or the prereleases for VS2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Mac is quite a different product to VS Win. As such, it's not possible to use extensions from one in the other.

To see extensions for VS Mac, access *Visual Studio* | *Extensions...* in the application itself.

That said, some of the *"extensions"* you're referring to above look more like what VS Win calls *workloads*. That is, they're an optional part of the product, rather than an extension. Do you see any of these options in the VS Mac installer?